# Popup appears then exits

Tags: php, javascript, popup, onsubmit

What is the code to have a popup appear then exit right after it loads?  i need to add conversion code to it to track conversions but do not want a thankyou page or redirection.

Also, anyway of hiding popup by making it small, last only like 2 seconds, or hidden behind the browser?

I want to put it on an onsubmit function for a form.

Comment: Maybe `<body onbeforeunload="return 'exit?'">`?

Comment: redirecting user to a new page using target="_blank"

Comment: sounds to me like you're doing something wrong if you want an invisible 2 seconds popup. Pay attention that many people use plugins on their browsers that block popups. Better describe what exactly you're trying to achieve and you might get interesting ideas from people here!

Answer (score 0):

may be thats what you are looking for

```
<div id="popupId">
 code for your popup
</div>
setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById('popupId').style.display='none';},2000);
```

Thanks